# Intermittent MySQL 5.6 Hibernate Error: Got error -1 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, hibernate, storage, innodb

I have an INNODB engine type table that intermittently throws the exception below.

From what I have read so far, the reason for this exception is one of the following

- A full disk
- Setting my.cnf innodb_force_recovery property to = 4
- Corrupted table

But none of these reasons apply in my case.

> 15:04:04,391 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (http--10.10.70.31-8080-2) SQL Error: 1030, SQLState: HY000
>   15:04:04,391 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (http--10.10.70.31-8080-2) Got error -1 from storage engine
>   15:04:04,410 ERROR
>   [com.ds.document.service.DocumentGenerationServiceImpl]
>   (http--10.10.70.31-8080-2) Error when persisting document
>   [AF-Worksheet] to case_document:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: o
>   rg.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Got error -1 from storage
>   engine
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.7.Final.jar:]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.7.Final.jar:]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1306)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.7.Final.jar:]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:888)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.7.Final.jar:]
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor595.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_14]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   [:1.6.0_14]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_14]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:]
>           at $Proxy265.merge(Unknown Source)      at com.ds.uadj.model.dao.CaseDocumentDAO.addOrUpdateCaseDocument(CaseDocumentDAO.java:266)
>   [uadj-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
>           at com.ds.uadj.model.service.CaseDocumentationServiceImpl.uploadDocument(CaseDocumentationServiceImpl.java:56)
>   [uadj-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]

**The intermittent/sporadic behavior baffled me.** 
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What does MySQL log say? see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595852/mysql-got-error-1-from-storage-engine-error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a MySQL bug on 5.6.10 version, which I use.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68722

It seems stable now after the upgrade.