# MySQL error on site login

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this generic error when trying to login to WordPress, or logging into Django, or trying to reimport a table (trying to debug the error):

## 1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine

MySQL.com says this about it:

> Error: 1030 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_GET_ERRNO)
>
> Message: Got error %d from storage engine
>
> Check the %d value to see what the OS error means. For example, 28
> indicates that you have run out of disk space.

But that still seems ambiguous to me. How do I find the OS error?  I have not found any help through Google searches, or mysqltuner, or restarting the services, or repairing through PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my.cnf had innodb_force_recovery set to 1.  What I don't understand is that it was working perfectly fine for months.

Also, I found this in one of the error logs (somehow there were two):

```
InnoDB: A new raw disk partition was initialized or
InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery is on: we do not allow
InnoDB: database modifications by the user. Shut down
InnoDB: mysqld and edit my.cnf so that newraw is replaced
InnoDB: with raw, and innodb_force_... is removed.
```

Found the solution to remove or set that value to 0, here:

[Mysql 'Got error -1 from storage engine' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595852/mysql-got-error-1-from-storage-engine-error)